# Cannot modify $item->modifiers in store_order_item_add_end hook

Tags: expresso-store, hook

I have an extension using the store_order_item_add_end hook.

I can set field values such as $item->price and $item->weight - but I cannot change the content of $item->modifiers.

I've also tried going via the $order->items array.

I have an existing modifier value I need to update. I can read its contents fine - but any changes I make are never reflected.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the key is to use:

$modifiers = $item->modifiers;

// modify the $modifiers data

$item->setModifiersAttribute($modifiers);

in the store_order_item_add_end hook.